# In Google Sheets grab the SUM of every cell where neighbouring cell is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to create a sheet for a cycling team where they need to register training participation and km riden.

Every rider has a column where they get a check for when they participate in the training. They get the group number they had (1,2,3), or a D if they where on the defect team.

In another sheet it's registered how long the training was.
This is then referenced in the bottom.

Why I need is in the last cell to sum up the distance they've ridden in relation to their participation.

[Training sessions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v09c6.png)

So in this example
They've had 4 training sessions. The distances registered in the bottom row.
Thomas participated in 3. He's ridden 148k in all in the 3 sessions.
Trine participated in 1. She's ridden 49k in the one session.

I have tried to manually validate every cell and grab the coerresponding value like this.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D4);0;$D$54)+IF(ISBLANK(E4);0;$E$54)+IF(ISBLANK(F4);0;$F$54)+IF(ISBLANK(G4);0;$G$54)+IF(ISBLANK(H4);0;$H$54)+IF(ISBLANK(I4);0;$I$54)+IF(ISBLANK(J4);0;$J$54)+IF(ISBLANK(K4);0;$K$54)+IF(ISBLANK(L4);0;$L$54)+IF(ISBLANK(M4);0;$M$54)+IF(ISBLANK(N4);0;$N$54)+IF(ISBLANK(O4);0;$O$54)+IF(ISBLANK(P4);0;$P$54)+IF(ISBLANK(Q4);0;$Q$54)+IF(ISBLANK(R4);0;$R$54)+IF(ISBLANK(S4);0;$S$54)+IF(ISBLANK(T4);0;$T$54)+IF(ISBLANK(U4);0;$U$54)+IF(ISBLANK(V4);0;$V$54)+IF(ISBLANK(W4);0;$W$54)
```

This works. But it's a nightmare to maintain.
If there's a session added, I have to dig through and add yet another IF statement in there.

Is there a better, hopefully a dynamic one, which addresses extra sessions??

Comment: Sounds like SUMIFS.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output